# Tomcat 8 not responding to OPTIONS request from CriOS

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, tomcat, cors

I have an application which uses POST requests with CORS for backend services (from `www.mydomain.com` to `api.mydomain.com`). The backend is provided by an Tomact8 server, a `CORSResponseFilter` has been implemented as follows:

```
public class CORSResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

   public void filter( ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext ) throws IOException {

       MultivaluedMap< String, Object > headers = responseContext.getHeaders();

       headers.add( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" );
       headers.add( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST" );
       headers.add( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type" );
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine, except for Chrome on iOS (Chrome on Android is working!). For this particular client, the Tomcat seems to refuse to respond to the pre-flight `OPTION` request. In the following the access log from Tomcat is shown:

```
10.10.10.9 - - [14/Sep/2015:20:55:45 +0200] "OPTIONS /api HTTP/1.1" 200 - "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/45.0.2454.68 Mobile/13B5110e Safari/600.1.4"
10.10.10.1 - - [14/Sep/2015:20:56:29 +0200] "OPTIONS /api HTTP/1.1" 200 561 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36"
```

The second line shows a request as it should be, one can see that in the first case the response has no size, therefore I think nothing is sent at all, where the second call is recieving a response of 561 bytes.

I do not know better methods then weinre for debugging Chrome on iOS, which only shows that the `POST` request starts but then never recieves a response (despite that Tomcat only recieves a`OPTIONS` request and no following `POST`)

On client side, the `superagent` library is used for `HTTP` calls.
I do not know if this issue is caused by the Tomcat server itself or by the client/browser, as it only happens for a certain device/browser combination (Chrome on iOS)

Did anybody experience similar behavior and can point me to the missing bits?

PS: yes the iPhone is running a pre-release iOS, but the same happens with regular iOS versions

UPDATE: Using WireShark I could extract the headers for the `OPTIONS` request from both, desktop and mobile.

from CriOS:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, origin, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Accept: */*,image/webp
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/45.0.2454.89 Mobile/13B5110e Safari/600.1.4
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

from desktop:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.6,de;q=0.4,ru;q=0.2
```

Something I noticed is the **image/webp** mediatype in the `ACCEPT` header, but also it has ***/***, so I'm not sure if this is relevant...

Comment: wish we could see the request headers.

Comment: would love to show them to you. Any idea how I could gather them on the mobile chrome @bayou.io?

Comment: @bayou.io found a way using WireShark, will update my question

Comment: given the new insight, I could identify: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287347/why-does-chrome-for-ios-insert-image-webp-content-type as possible related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with reference to [Why does Chrome for iOS insert image/webp content-type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287347/why-does-chrome-for-ios-insert-image-webp-content-type) I could tackle this issue by manipulating the request headers on the server itself:

```
public class CroISRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter( final ContainerRequestContext requestContext ) throws IOException {

        if (requestContext.getHeaders().getFirst( "accept" ).equals( "*/*,image/webp" )) requestContext.getHeaders().putSingle( "accept", "*/*" );
    }
}
```

This filter simply overwrites any ***/*,image/webp** content-type to a straight ***/***, allowing the server to respond with **text/plain** which enables CORS on the client side (CriOS).